# React-router: true way to propagate route-component props/state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, flux

**Question:** isn't it an anti-pattern to pass component props/state via `location.state`? May you suggest a better way?

I have some social site, where each user may create his own profile. Each profile is an `UserProfile` component, which are routed like:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={History}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
            <Route path="profile" component={UserProfile} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

And I need to make a redirect on user click to specific user profile from multiple places of my site. I do that like:

```
// Where server response contains username, surname, some counters etc.
Service.getUserSummary(userId).then(response => {
  History.pushState(reponse, '/profile');
});
```

And retrieve `response` at `UserProfile`:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

  render() {
    // QUESTION: isn't it an anti-pattern? Is there any better way?
    const state = this.props.location.state,
          username = state.username,
          ............
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deal with profiles distinguished by ID, the best way is to include the ID in the URL:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={History}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
            <Route path="profile/:userId" component={UserProfile} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

This `id` will then be available inside `UserProfile` as `this.props.params.userId`.

A better practice is to load data from the server *after* the redirect, not *before* or *during* it. So, you have 3 stages of showing profile page:

1. Just before the user clicked the link;
2. User clicked the link, router has redirected to User Profile page, but it's still empty ("loading...");
3. Data has been arrived from the server, state of `UserProfile` component has been updated, and it's re-rendered with the new data.

In the simplest way the data can be retrieved in `componentDidMount()` method and set to the state (see https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html):

```
var UserProfile = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: null,
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {

    // Your code for fetching user data from server:
    Service.getUserSummary(this.props.params.userId).then(response => {
      if (this.isMounted()) {
        this.setState({
          data: response.data
        });
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    if (!this.state.data) {

        // Rendering stage (2)
        return (<div>Loading...</div>);
    }

    // Rendering stage (3)
    return (
      <div>
        I am {this.state.data.userName}!
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```